# Microsoft Bot framework error in azure Webchat

Tags: dialog, botframework, bots, chatbot

I am getting error while calling the this.dialog inside the onmessage function.

```
        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
        if(d == "true")
        {
            await context.sendActivity("token is there");

        }
        else{
            await this.dialog.run(context, this.dialogState);
            await next();
        }
}
```

d value will be false so control goes to else part but after going to else part I am getting error.

Error message: The bot encountered an error or bug. 
               To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.

Comment: Have you defined "d" somewhere? I pasted this in and it works as expected, but I defined "d" which you haven't included in your pasted code. Without it defined it dies, not surprisingly.

Comment: Yes, I defined  "d" still I am getting error